# Sincronización SD Offline manual

Tags: genexus

```
Genexus 15 u5
```

`.net`

Estoy con sincronización manual y deseo enviar una tabla de parámetros al device. 
Vi que hay una forma de [precargar la base offline](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?22298,HowTo%3A%20Create%20offline%20SD%20applications%20with%20a%20preloaded%20database,), pero me gustaría si es posible, que sea mediante `sincronization.recieve()` (aunque use sincro manual) y que solo envie una tabla de parámetros. Es posible? Porque empecé a tocar las conditions y me envía muchas mas tablas que son offline y solo necesito la de parámetros, para desde ahí armar mi sincro manual.

Comment: La sincronización desde el servidor hacia el cliente se hace con `Synchronization.Receive()`, no con `.Send()`... Supongo que fue lo que quisiste poner...

Comment: Si debí poner  `sincronization.recieve()`, ya lo arregle.

Answer (score 2):

En la sincronización desde el servidor al dispositivo (*receive*), no hay forma de restringir el conjunto de tablas que participan. Las tablas que se sincronizan son todas las que utiliza la aplicación.

Lo que sí se puede hacer -a pesar de que la tabla se sincronice- es no llevar datos para una determinada tabla. Para eso, lo que debes hacer es poner una condición que no sea cumplida por ningún registro de la tabla.

Por ejemplo, si tengo una tabla de `Clientes` cuyo identificador es un campo numérico que siempre va a ser positivo, podría poner la condición `ClienteId = 0` en el objeto `Offline Database`. De esa forma no va a ir ningún registro a la tabla `Clientes` con la sincronización automática.

Comment: Si entiendo, al final lo resolví usando la precarga offline.  El tema es que aveces necesitamos tener unos datos iniciales en el SD y cambiar la BD sqlite, es un poco engorroso. Me gustaría que se pueda enviar un archivo "config.ini" o algo así, adjuntarlo a Genexus y que se pueda editar en Genexus o en WEB y en el dispo.  solo para ingresar unas pocas constantes. Por ejemplo la url de algún webservice a consumir,  IP, etc. es solo una sugerencia. Gracias Marcos